# AlarmManager and Force Stop

Tags: android, alarmmanager, forceclose

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

If you use the **AlarmManager** all added alarms are **cleared** if:

1. The device is rebooted
2. The app is updated
3. Force Stop of the app

**Solutions** for readding the alarms are easy for the first 2, but the 3. are a huge problem:

1. BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast
2. PACKAGE_UPDATED Broadcat
3. ????

So does anyone have a solution for 3?

I now that **Force Stop** of the app **kills the complete app** and the app and all broadcast are only getting **active again** if the **user starts** the app manually.
This is OK, but I need a way to **readd** my alarms to the AlarmManager **after** the user **reopens** the app.

**For example:**

- User opens app and adds one alarm in 30 minutes
- After 15 minutes a system app or task killer app force stops the app and all alarms are deleted
- After 20 minutes the user opens the app again **AFTER the force stop**, now I want to readd the alarm to the AlarmManager

A solution would be to readd all alarms after **every start** of the app, but this **isn't possible** because it is a reminder app and some users have **over 100 reminders** added.
I can't add over 100 alarms on every start of the app.

So I need a way to see/check if my app was force stopped earlier.

Now after a force stop all "old" reminders/alarms are never getting active again. Only new created alarms are working.
Really bad user experience :-(

Comment: "I need a way to readd my alarms to the AlarmManager after the user reopens the app" -- if you have not received an alarm in too long when your activity is started, reschedule your alarms. Note that for most users and most devices, "force stop" is not a casual action, and so users should not expect your app to behave afterwards. "I can't add over 100 alarms on every start of the app" -- since you only have one alarm, this should not be a problem. If you are scheduling 100 alarms for 100 reminders, you have bigger problems.

Comment: How do you mean this exactly? Should I add all 100 alarms every 30 minutes if the user opens the app If I don't received an alarm within an time frame of 30 minutes?

Yeah I know that this is not a casual action BUT i get a lot user feedback that my alarms are not fired and if they open the app they see that all are overdue.

So it seems to me that some phone manufactors are force stopping the app to save battery or some task killer apps does this. 

The user doesn't know that the app is force stopped. This is the huge problem!

Comment: "Should I add all 100 alarms every 30 minutes if the user opens the app" -- no, you should add one alarm, for the first reminder. In this universe, time flows linearly. Add the alarm for the next reminder when the first one happens. "If I don't received an alarm within an time frame of 30 minutes?" -- having a second alarm that serves as a "heartbeat" to more rapidly detect a force-close is a possibility. The cost is battery life for *all* your users.

Comment: "So it seems to me that some phone manufactors are force stopping the app to save battery or some task killer apps does this" -- third-party apps should not be able to force-stop apps. There are some devices where the manufacturer added their own task manager, where the task manager does a force-stop. This is idiotic on the part of the device manufacturer, and I yell at every manufacturer that I get a chance to about this.